# Android weighted fragment not showing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Basically what I'm trying to do is have half the screen be a tab layout and half an image (or really anything else). It works just fine until I start adding weight.

As is, nothing is displayed. What would cause this problem?

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="#00025a">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/test_room_1"/>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Without the weight component the tab related stuff displays, but I'm assuming it pushes the image out as it isn't shown.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**UPDATE**:

Here's a screenshot as requested: [Weighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hN8W.png)

And the calling activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class sandbox_mode extends FragmentActivity {
    ImageView level_background;

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sandbox_mode_play);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Enemy Tab").setIndicator("Enemies"),
                enemy_tab.class, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot ?

Comment: how you are calling this fragment. please add that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation on `FragmentTabHost` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html), you'll see that it's not inherited from `LinearLayout`, so basically layout_weight is not supported by this container. I would suggest adding additional top `LinearLayout` for this to work correctly.

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="left"
android:weightSum="2"
android:background="#00025a">
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="2" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/test_room_1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me. Back to slogging through more android junk I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

use **childFragmentManager** instead FragmentManager

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);
```

If you want to use nested fragments within a **native Fragment**. use `getFragmentManager()`.

If you want to use nested fragments within a **support library Fragment**, use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: do I need an additional include to use 'getChildFragmentManager()'?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/21064614/2826147 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17236958/2826147

Comment: I've already looked at that. That's the main reason I'm this far.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() isn't a thing for me in this context. Specifically "cannot resolve method 'getChildFragmentManager()"

Comment: so what you have checked from above link i have mentioned.